# How to use wait() and notify() in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex

As I understand, I am suppose to call wait() on the mutex, when I want the current thread to stop working until another thread calls notify() on the same mutex object. That doesn't seem to be working.

I'm trying to make a thread print 1-10. Then wait for another thread to print 11-20. And then the first thread would again print 21-30

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Object mutex = 1;

        Thread child1 = new Thread(new Child1(mutex));
        Thread child2 = new Thread(new Child2(mutex));

        child1.start();
        child2.start();

    }

}
```

**Child1.java**

```
public class Child1 implements Runnable {
    Object mutex;

    public Child1(Object mutex){
        this.mutex = mutex;
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++){
                System.out.println(c+1);
            }

            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        for(int c = 20; c < 31; c++){
            System.out.println(c+1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Child2.java**

```
public class Child2 implements Runnable {
    Object mutex;

    public Child2(Object mutex) {
        this.mutex = mutex;
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            for (int c = 11; c < 21; c++) {
                System.out.println(c);
            }
            notify();
        }

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17Exception in thread "Thread-0" 
18
19
20
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at task42.Child1.run(Child1.java:18)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at task42.Child2.run(Child2.java:15)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, output added.

Comment: What are you calling wait and notify on? Not on the mutex! Your code calls these methods on the current object that the methods are called in, the `this` of Child1 and Child2, not on the mutex.

Comment: You are wait() Child1 thread and notify() Child2 thread. You have to call wait() and notify() on the same thread.

Comment: @BKBatchelor: you don't call wait and notify on a Thread (well you *can* since a Thread *is* an object -- but you don't want to) but rather on an object.

Comment: The notify() is calling instance of Child2, but you wait the instance of Child1

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, thanks! Calling on the mutex did the job.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels your answer makes sense because the op put a lock on mutex and on not the whole object, so notify and wait must be applied to the mutex variable which is type object. Did I get that right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must add the `mutex` reference to `wait()` and `notify()`; that is, change `wait()` to `mutex.wait()` and `notify()` to `mutex.notify()`.

Without this, you are calling to wait/notify on `this` (`method()` is equivalent to `this.method()`)

Here is your code with the appropriate changes made:

Child1.java

```
public class Child1 implements Runnable {
    Object mutex;

    public Child1(Object mutex){
        this.mutex = mutex;
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            for(int c = 0; c < 10; c++){
                System.out.println(c+1);
            }

            try {
                mutex.wait(); // Changed here
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        for(int c = 20; c < 31; c++){
            System.out.println(c+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Child2.java

```
public class Child2 implements Runnable {
    Object mutex;

    public Child2(Object mutex) {
        this.mutex = mutex;
    }

    public void run() {
        synchronized (mutex) {
            for (int c = 11; c < 21; c++) {
                System.out.println(c);
            }
            mutex.notify(); // Changed here
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The only sensible way to use `wait` is within a 'conditional loop' that loops until a certain condition becomes `true` (or `false`). Threads might wake up by chance - even without `notify`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code fails in several ways.

First of all, there is no guarantee, that the first thread will also run first. (Especially on multi-cores, there is a high chance, that both run in parallel). So if the second thread enteres the `synchronized` block of `Child2.run()` first, it will call `mutex.notify()` even before the first thread is in wait state. As a result, the first thread will stay in `mutex.wait()` forever.

Second, `wait()` / `notify()` are not thought to be used as thread-handshake-mechanism directly. This could only work if you could guarantee that the first thread calls `wait()` *before* the second thread calls `notify()`. Usually, you can't.

Instead, `wait()` should be used to wait for a certain *condition* to become true. The condition is usually changed by another thread, who notifies the waiting thread by calling `notifyAll()`. So the handshake-mechanism is the condition, not `wait` / `notify`:

```
// 1st thread:
synchronized (lock) {
    while (!condition) {
        lock.wait();
    }
    // continue
}

// 2nd thread:
synchronized {
    condition = true;
    lock.notifyAll();
}
```

Any other usage-pattern of `wait()` / `notify()` or `notifyAll()` is wrong! It is also very important to *always* call `wait()` inside a loop as a thread might wake up on chance - even without `notify()` or `notifyAll()`.

**Using `wait()/notifyAll()`**

So in your case, you could use `wait()` and `notifyAll()` in combination with a stage-variable:

```
public class Mutex {
    static final Object lock = new Object();
    static int stage = 1;

    static void first() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            // we're already in stage 1
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) System.out.println(i);

            // enter stage 2
            stage = 2;
            lock.notifyAll();

            // wait for stage 3
            while (stage != 3) { lock.wait(); }

            // now we're in stage 3
            for(int i = 20; i < 30; ++i) System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    static void second() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (lock) {
            // wait for stage 2
            while (stage != 2) { lock.wait(); }

            // now we're in stage 2
            for(int i = 20; i < 30; ++i) System.out.println(i);

            // enter stage 3
            stage = 3;
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Mutex.first();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Mutex.second();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```