# Wait and notify as controller-worker synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I'm trying to learn to use wait and notify.

I need an application that every 10 seconds ask to the user if the thread has to continue working or not.
If not (the user presses n) the thread has to wait until the user writes 'y' on the console.

I have to use wait and notify but I don't know how to.

I'm trying to implement the wait and the notify without the prompt from the user.

This is the main class which creates two threads, FolderThread is the thread which has to work and ControlThread is the one who has to ask to the user if he wants to continue or not.

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        FolderThread folder = new FolderThread();
        Thread t = new Thread(folder);
        ControlThread control = new ControlThread(folder);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(control);
        t.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

FolderThread

```
public class FolderThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("started");
            synchronized(this) {
                try {
                    this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ControlThread

```
public class ControlThread implements Runnable {

    FolderThread folder;

    public ControlThread (FolderThread folder) {
        this.folder = folder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(folder) {
            folder.notify();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it prints "Started" and then it waits for a notify that will never come! Why?

Comment: What happens if your `ControlThread` goes first?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis nothing change

Comment: That's not what I mean. Thread execution is not deterministic. If by some chance, the thread for `ControlThread` goes first and executes `notify` before the other thread has had a chance to `wait`, what do you expect to happen? Or even what happens if the `notify` comes after the `wait`, you thread goes back to `wait` in the next iteration.

Comment: I would check for deadlock.  Technically this is a race condition.  In one case your thread waits and never gets notified.  In the other condition I think you will have a deadlock. Use visual vim

Comment: Use Visual VM to check for dead lock.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use wait() and notify() in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378687/how-to-use-wait-and-notify-in-java)

Comment: To explain what is going on add print outs before and after each wait, notify, and synchronize.

Comment: While not exactly the OP's question, I feel this code could be improved by the use of a Java [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).  The `isDone()` method is useful here.

Comment: Do you have to use `wait()` and `notify()`, like for a (misguided) homework assignment? They are a somewhat obsolete and often not the right solution any more.

Comment: @erickson, what is the modern replacement for this mechanism ?

Comment: In this case, I'd create a single-thread `ExecutorService`, submit the folder task to it, `shutdown()`, then await termination with a timeout in a loop. If the user indicates cancelation at any of the timeouts, you can call `shutdownNow()`. This will interrupt the worker thread, so your task should respond to interrupts.

Comment: Re, "...every ten seconds has to ask the user...", but what if the user does not respond within ten seconds?

Comment: @erickson thanks. Indeed I was thinking that we could simply have the main thread launch the worker thread, and simply interrupt it when user presses n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that your `notify` is working, but it isn't doing anything else than just "waking up" the other thread, until it goes back to waiting, and then the control thread is done, so it never "wakes up" again the second thread.

Basically, if you want to not write the user input part, you can simulate with

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
// and then do what would be done if the user had type 'y'
```

In that case, the remaining problem is that when you notify your other thread, nothing gets done. So you need 2 things :

1. set a "flag" somewhere, so for example pass a shared Boolean to both threads. your control thread should set that Boolean to true to tell other thread that it should stop
2. read the "flag" from your worker thread every time he is waken up, to check whether he should stop or not

So the modifications you should do :

1. Create an AtomicBoolean in main method :

   ```
   AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean();
   ```
2. Pass that AtomicBoolean to constructors of both threads :

   ```
   FolderThread folder = new FolderThread(flag);
   ControlThread control = new ControlThread(folder, flag);
   ```

   Of course you will need to adapt the constructor declarations.
3. Get FolderThread to check on the flag when it wakes up. Replace `while(true)` by

   ```
   while(flag.get() == false)
   ```
4. Get ControlThread to update the flag when it wants to stop it :

   ```
   flag.set( true );
   ```

It is worth noting though, that to implement a simple worker-controller relationship, where communication is limited to stopping the worker thread, you don't need `wait` and `notify`. You can simply have the controller thread interrupt the worker thread using `t.interrupt()`

Comment: Yes, the problem was that! the ControlThread was doing the notify but when the FolderThread was calling again the method wait there wasn't any thread that could call notify. So I used a while-do in the Control-Thread

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution (with the input from the user)

FolderThread

```
    public class FolderThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Checking...");

            synchronized(this) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ControlThread

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ControlThread implements Runnable {

    FolderThread folder;

    public ControlThread (FolderThread folder) {
        this.folder = folder;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(true) {

            InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);

            try {   
                do {
                    System.out.println("Continue? y/n");

                }
                while(br.readLine().equals("n"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            synchronized(folder) {
                folder.notify();
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Try reading vic's amswer again. Also see the oracle tutorial on guarded blocks.